# Matplotlib plots adding extra points to chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am new to plotting data in python and I am a bit confused about the results I am seeing. I have the following function defined:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import pylab

def plot_data():
    value = [300,320,230,402,320]
    axis = [0,1,2,3,4]
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(axis,value)
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()

plot_data()
```

All I want is a simple line chart that will plot the value by the axis. When I run this code, I get the following image:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/R9NXG]

I am unsure where those 4 points are being generated from and I would like for them not to be there. I apologize if this has been asked, I couldn't figure out the right wording to find direct answers to this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am in python3.6 and I have version 2.0.2 of matplotlib (sorry for all the edits :-) )

Comment: Just as a note, I cannot reproduce in Python 3.4 or 2.7 and I have the same version of matplotlib as you. Might be something in 3.6 which is causing the problem

Comment: *sigh* well thanks anyways for trying!

Comment: Are you sure that there is no sneaky bit of code somewhere in your script that you forgot to comment out? That would be the easiest explanation

Comment: Ahaa! I did have something I forgot to comment out. I'm a dumbo, thanks for the help!!